# How to setup a Apache Web Server on Azure Web Role

Tags: azure

I need to setup a apache Web Server on my Azure Cloud Web Role to run a python app on localhost that the webrole website can proxy its requests to, but I cant seem to find any resources on setting up an apache web server.

Since its a web role, i would like a solution where its just to extract a zip file with the apache webserver and run it on startup and not requiring me to install someting manual on the machine.

Have anyone some example code of setting up apache http server from c# code.

Comment: Remember that a Web Role has IIS running. That would most likely collide with Apache. Your logical choice would be to run Apache in a Worker Role instead, which doesn't run IIS by default.

Comment: true, webrole was a typo. I found a solution. will add answer soonish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AzureRunMe](https://github.com/azure-contrib/AzureRunMe) project. I have written [detailed blog post on how to use Azure RunMe to host Jetty server on Worker Roles](http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/08/running-java-jetty-server-on-azure-with.html). These can be of a good start for running just apache. Later, if you also wish session affinity, you may check out my [SessionAffinity plugin for Azure SDK](https://github.com/richorama/AzurePluginLibrary/tree/master/plugins/SessionAffinity4). And this [blog post on how to use it](http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/07/sessionaffinity-plugin-for-windows-azure.html) and [update](http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/08/azure-sessionaffinity-plugin-update.html).
If you have any issues drop them here, or directly report as issue on the respective github page.

Comment: I just vent over your posts on session affinity and while I understand the concept, i am not sure if i need it or not.  If the application is stateless, it dont matter as I see it.  I get the impression from your posts that there is something unique to apache / tomcat that by default requiress session affinity? is this the case? or if the applicaation running on apache is stateless also, then i can just skip session affinity?